# Determine which callback invoked throw(:abort) in Rails 5

Tags: callback, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

Given a Model in which a callback invoked `throw(:abort)`, how can one determine which callback did the deed **without modifying the callbacks themselves**?

For example, the following Model...

```
class OddDuck < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :random_abort_1
  before_save :random_abort_2

  private

  def random_abort_1
    if Random.rand(2) == 1
      throw(:abort)
    end
  end

  def random_abort_2
    if Random.rand(2) == 1
      throw(:abort)
    end
  end
end
```

... will sometimes fail to save ...

```
$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 81303
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
irb(main):001:0> OddDuck.create!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to save the record
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:152:in `save!'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save!'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:30:in `save!'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `block in save!'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `save!'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:45:in `save!'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/alice/Desktop/site/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/alice/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

... but it is not readily apparent from the backtrace which callback caused the abort.

Answer (score 2):

[throw](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-throw) also accepts an optional return value, so you can use that if you need to know the callback that triggered the `throw`.

> **throw(tag [, obj])**
>   Transfers control to the end of the active `catch` block waiting for `tag`. Raises `UncaughtThrowError` if there is no `catch` block for the `tag`. The optional second parameter supplies a return value for the `catch` block, which otherwise defaults to `nil`.
>   https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-throw

For example:

```
def random_abort_1
  if Random.rand(2) == 1
    throw(:abort, __method__)
  end
end
```

Will return `random_abort_1`.

Comment: +1 for an on-point answer to my original question. After seeing your answer I realized that the question needed to be clarified. I've updated the question.

Comment: @kkurian I'll update my answer so it tells you which `model_name#action_name` triggered the throw. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.